# Equivalent of BigInteger value of C++ long long

Tags: java, c++, biginteger

I am migrating some code base from C++ to Java where I encountered a `long long` value in the C++ code which i need to migrate.

On some research i found out I should be using `BigInteger` to represent the `long long` of C++.

I looked at couple of examples and found out the syntax to be :

```
static BigInteger flag1 = BigInteger.valueOf(0x00000001);
```

Here i noticed the value used in the argument for BigInteger.valueOf is not the same as original `long long` value which was `0x0000000000000001LL`

Original value had 16 digits and this one had 8 digits and does not include `LL` suffix at the end. Can someone explain what is going on ?

Also If they can suggest the value of `0x0000000000000200LL` in similar terms.

Comment: I fail to see why you think you need `BigInteger` in Java. That's an arbitrary precision  type, quite inefficient. Just use `long` in Java. It's 64 bits, which is the same as the guaranteed minimum for C++ `long long`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note: all those zeros ... don't matter. There is no difference between 0x1; and 0x001, and so on. As long as we are talking about **numbers**.

It would be a different thing if those were represented as **strings**; then of coursre "0x1" is not the same string as "0x01". But well, they aren't.

All of your values are number literals; and they are all in a range that would even fit into ordinary *long* values in Java.

In other words: **leading** zero digits do not matter for numbers (except for an example like 010, which is something else than 10; as starting 0 indicate octal numbers).

The more interesting question would actually would be: what literal value the compiler puts into the java bytecode for that.

Comment: So, you suggest 0x0000000000000200LL equivalent would be 0x00000200 ?

Comment: 0x200; again leading zeros do not matter.

Comment: Great Answer. Thanks a lot @ghostcat

Answer (score 2):

0x0000000000000001LL == 0x00000001 == 0x1 == 1 (dec)

0x0000000000000200LL == 0x00000200 == 0x200 = 512 (dec)

Those are small values and can be represented as a regular int.

You can also use BigInteger is you need.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things to learn here:

1. You probably don't need to use `BigInteger` here at all.  The C++ `long long` type is a signed 64 bit integer on most systems (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).  But Java has a 64 bit signed integer type - `long`.  So unless you are porting C++ code that was designed for an architecture where `long long` is greater than 64 bits (!), a Java `long` is what you need to use.
2. Leading zeros don't matter in hexadecimal literals (i.e. `0x...`) in Java.

   (They matter for decimal literals though, because a leading zero turns a "decimal" literal into an octal literal ... which alters its value.  For instance, the literal `010` represents the number eight!)
3. If you actually do need 64 bit integer literal in Java, then put an `L` on the right hand end.  Integer literals are assumed to be 32 bit.
4. In a context like this where you are trying to use `BigInteger(long)`, a 32 bit integer literal would be *widened* to 64 bits anyway.

---

So in your case:

```
static BigInteger flag1 = BigInteger.valueOf(0x00000001); 
static BigInteger flag1 = BigInteger.valueOf(0x0000000000000001); 
static BigInteger flag1 = BigInteger.valueOf(0x1);
static BigInteger flag1 = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
static BigInteger flag1 = BigInteger.valueOf(1L);
```

are all saying the same thing.  This is saying the same thing too ...

```
static BigInteger flag1 = BigInteger.valueOf(01);
```

... but it is a bad idea.  It only works because "1" octal and "1" decimal are the same number.

---

Someone asked:

> The more interesting question would actually would be: what literal value the compiler puts into the java bytecode for that.

I don't think that the JLS specifies this, but it would use a long literal because that is what the JVM spec requires.